# Dart: Check items in List of lists

Tags: list, dart

Before adding a list I want to check that it does not exist so there are no repeated values. This works with a list of integers, but not with a list of other integer lists:

```dart
void main() {
  var listasN = List<int>();
  var n1 = 1;
  var n2 = 2;
  var n3 = 1;
  void addN(int n) {
    if (!listasN.contains(n)) {
      listasN.add(n);
    }
  }
  addN(n1);
  addN(n2);
  addN(n3);
  print(listasN);

  var listas = List<List<int>>();
  var lista1 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  var lista2 = [5, 6, 7, 8];
  var lista3 = [1, 2, 3, 4];
  void addLista(List<int> ls) {
    if (!listas.contains(ls)) {
      listas.add(ls);
    }
  }
  addLista(lista1);
  addLista(lista2);
  addLista(lista3);
  print(listas);
}
```

Out:

```
[1, 2]
[[1, 2, 3, 4], [5, 6, 7, 8], [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

The first function does not support repeated values, but the second does, why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dart lists do not have an inherent equality. That is, the `==` operator only considers lists equal if it's the same list, not if it's different lists with the same content.
That's generally how Dart handles equality of mutable types. The `contains` method uses equality for checking.

So, what you can do instead is to create a "list equals" method:

```dart
bool listEquals<T>(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
  if (list1.length != list2.length) return false;
  for (var i = 0; i < list1.length; i++) {
    if (list1[i] != list2[i]) return false;
  }
  return true;
}
```

Then you can check if a *similar* list is contained in your lists:

```dart
void addLista(List<int> ls) {
  if (!listas.any((ls2) => listEquals(ls, ls2))) {
    listas.add(ls);
  }
}
```

Comment: OK thank you very much. A detail: I think it is necessary to close ) in: if (!listas.any((ls2) => listEquals(ls, ls2))) {: